# How to cut a string using 2 delimiters

Tags: c, string, delimiter

How to cut a string using 2 delimiters in C?

I'm getting a string from the user in this platform:

```
cp <path1> <path2>
```

I need to get the pathes into a new string (each path to one string).

I tried to use `strstr` and `strtok` but it doesn't work.

I don't know the length of the pathes. I also just know that they are starting with `" \"` (this are the delimiters that I have (`space + \`)).

this is what i tried
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
int main()
{
  char *c;
  char *ch = malloc(1024);
  while (strcmp(ch, "exit"))
  {
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", ch); //what was the input (cp /dor/arthur /king/apple)
    c = malloc(sizeof(strlen(ch) + 1));
    strcpy(c, ch);
    char *pch = strtok(c, " //");
    printf("this is : %s \n", pch); //printed "this is: cp"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? strstr and strtok allow you to locate stuff in a string, they should be perfect for the job.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: And you are sure there are no blanks (spaces) in the pathes themselfs?

Comment: OT: Instead of using `char * c = malloc(strlen(ch) + 1); strcpy(c, ch);` you might like to simply use `char * c = strdup(ch);`.

Comment: `sizeof(strlen(ch) + 1))` returns the size of `size_t` which is 4 or 8 depending whether you are on a 32 or 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) . the above link contains an example of using `strtok().`

you cans use the 2 delimeters  (`space + \`) with `strtok()` in this way:

```
str = strtok(str, " \\");
```

Comment: You should really try to understand the example linked in the answer.

Comment: `strtok` locates the first of *any* of the delimiters, so in this case it will break up the input on each space *or* backslash. The OP should use `strstr` instead.

Comment: @Jongware. This not truth from the cplusplus `char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );`

Split string into tokens
A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters that are part of delimiters.

Answer (score -1):

Is in the main function? If it is, main function has argc (int) and *argv[] (string) parameters which you can do what you want.

Comment: How about changing a little your code? You can use int main (int argc, char *arg[]) instead of malloc and you pass those strings in your program parameters, with that you can do what you show in your commentary (//what was the input...)

Comment: i can't do it i need to do it by scanf

Comment: But as you can see, if you execute your program like ./cp /dor/arthur /king/apple nothing does until you write something so the scanf will catch the string.

Comment: You can see this example about strtok: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) it would help you.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer to anything.